# Google Sheets Create Template

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a Google Sheet that I want to save as a template. Different people will re-use the template on a daily basis, then save/share their daily data inputs.

I cannot find how to do this and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation from `I have created a Google Sheet that I want to save as a template. Different people will re-use the template on a daily basis, then save/share their daily data inputs.`. In your situation, do you want to create a new Google Spreadsheet using a template Google Spreadsheet? Or, do you want to insert a new sheet to an existing Google Spreadsheet using a template sheet? In this case, I think that a script is required to be used. In your situation, how do you want to run the script?

Comment: I have created a custom Google Sheet. I do not want to use one of Google's existing templates.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Is your account in a google workspace or is it using personal gmail?

Comment: Google Workspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### If it is for Google Workspace:

Here's what you can do if it's part of Google Workspace.

1.) From the Google Sheets Home Page ([Sheets](https://sheets.google.com)) -> select **Template gallery**
[image]

2.) Select your Organization Name. Then **Submit Template**

[image]

3.) Then select the Spreadsheet you want to make a template and select the category for it.
[image]

4.) It should then appear in the template gallery under your organization name. Here is also where the other users from your organization can access the template
[image]

### If using personal Gmail accounts:

Otherwise, if you are only using personal Gmail accounts and want to share a template with other users I suggest the following workaround:

1.) Open the spreadsheet you want to make a template and add the word "Template" to its file name. (This is just so other users will not edit the actual file)

2.) Select the Folder Icon next to the filename
[image]

3.) Click new folder to create a folder which you will be sharing access for other users. Type a name for the folder, the name does not matter but I suggest you name it something like **Google Sheets Templates** or **Custom Templates**

4.) Move the Spreadsheet file to that folder.

5A.) Share the file to the other users and only allow for view access to prevent them from accidentally editing the original spreadsheet.

5B.) Or from your google drive you can share the access to other users to that **Custom Templates Folder** so they can access all templates you put in this drive folder.
[image]

6.) Manually make a copy of the file to use it as a template.

[image]

**See below references for more info:**

- [Create Template - Workspace/Organization](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308885?hl=en)
- [Create Template - Personal](https://www.howtogeek.com/448828/how-to-create-a-google-sheets-template/)

Comment: Thank you, but I do not see my organization's name in the Template Gallery.

Comment: @CountryMusic Are you sure it is a Google Workspace account?